# How to investigate cherrypy crashing?

Tags: cherrypy

We have a cherrypy service that integrates with several backend web services. During load testing cherrypy process is regularly crashed after a while (45 minutes). We know the bottleneck is the backend web services we are using. Before crashing we see 500 and 503 errors when accessing the backend services, but I can't figure why cherrypy itself will crash (the whole process was killed). Can you give me ideas how to investigate where the problem is? Is it possible that the thread_poll (50) is queueing up too many requests?

Comment: Does CherryPy throw any exceptions when it crashes?  
Do you use multiprocessing.Queue anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

In my early CherryPy days I had it crashing once. I mean a Python process crash caused by a *segfault*. When I investigated it I found that I messed with MySQLdb connections, caching them in objects which were accessed by CherryPy threads interchangeably. Because a MySQLdb connection is not thread-safe it should be accessed only from the thread in was created in. Also because of concurrency involved the crashes seemed nondeterministic, and only appeared in load-testing. So load-testing can work as a debugging tool here -- try [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or [Locust](http://locust.io/) (Pythonic).

When a process crashes you can instruct Linux to write a core dump which will have a stack trace (e.g. on MySQLdb C-code side in my example). However alien low-level C environment is to you (it is to me), the stack trace can help find what library is causing the crash or at least narrow a circle of suspects. Here is [an article about it](http://mytechrants.wordpress.com/2009/05/22/debugging-a-segmentation-fault-using-gdb/).

Also I want to note that unlikely problem is in CherryPy. It is actually very stable.